Why is my import of the contents of binary file using Data failing at runtime?
I'm attempting to learn Swift.  I'm writing and testing a Class to encapsulate variables and methods to process a binary file of UInt16 values to produce and display a GCImage in an app for testing the Class which displays the grayscale image as the ultimate test.
At this point most everything worked and I was tidying up the code.  Suddenly importing the file  using Data produced a runtime error.  The file could not be read.
Consulting Dr. Google was a waste of time. In the meantime I compared the file path input as a String vs the generated URL.  The only difference was that spaces had been replaced by '%20'. I finally created some debug code to test that the data file actually existed (it's in my file tree) and was readable - it is.  I have inspected the entitlements file and the app is not Sandboxed and read permission is 'Yes'. (In the process I somehow damaged the entitlements file, couldn't recreate it so had to create a new app and copy all the code.)  The error persists.
XCode and Swift are up-to-date, the app is only for macOS which is up-to-date.
The paths below are copied from debug data
    imagePath = (String)    "/Users/nate/2023 02 22 1330 SwiftDecomTestData/rawPlus/DN/IR3_2017-12-08_018_029_dn.raw"   
    fileURL Foundation.URL? "/Users/nate/2023%2002%2022%201330%20SwiftDecomTestData/rawPlus/DN/IR3_2017-12-08_018_029_dn.raw"


The code snippet where the error occurs.
    private func importAndScaleImageData() {
        // Start DEBUG verification
        let filePath = self.imagePath  // data file
        if checkIfFileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            print("file exists!")
            if !checkFileReadability(filePath: filePath) {
                print("Unable to read the file.")
                print("imagePath \(filePath)")
                fatalError()
            }
        } else {
            print("file does not exist!")
            fatalError()
        }
        // No runtime errors above #########
        // END DEBUG verification

        do { // NOTE input file path as String was cast as URL
            let data8 = try Data(contentsOf: self.fileURL!) // ERROR
            self.backingImage = data8.uint16Array() // not reached
        } catch { // error caught here #######
            print("importAndScaleImageData: URL \(self.fileURL!)  \(error)")
            fatalError("Error found importing \(self.fileURL!.absoluteString)")
        }

           // remainder of the method skipped 

        }
        

The error code is
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

The question was not previewed in the SE editor, is this new?

What is the output of your code?  At what point is it failing? at the Data(contentsOf)? What is the error you are catching?

The  line that stats with: "let data8 " is where the error is. The last line of the post is the error message. I know that the file is readable from the above tests and that it can be read and displayed from other apps such as Fiji.

It's a bad url. I would expect the url to start with file:. A simple path is not a url.

@Paulw11  This is where the file path "newFile''as a String was used to create the url, is this wrong?  self.fileURL = URL(string: newFile)

@Paulw11 That's what it was.  Creating the URL version this way worked.  "self.fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: newFile)" You should take credit by posting the answer.
